# Dymosim Simulate Operation

Tags: scripting, dymola

Good Night,

I am not able to understand the operation principle of the following function

system("dymosin -s dsin.mat result.mat")

I know that dsin.mat is the simulation command input and result.mat is the file where the result of the simulation are storaged.

I do not see changes in my model and sometimes it works and another times no. When it is not operation it gives me an output of [2]

Really thanks for your help

ichubi

I would like to use the function in a for cycle where i enter different input parameters in the dsin.mat to my model.Sometimes it even delete the result.mat that i have created with a dymola simulation of the model

I use the function with a simple model(without for cycle) and it was working but suddenly does not operate

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to sweep a parameter? If so there is built-in support Dymola to do that.

Comment: Hi Dag, yes i want to sweep parameters but running an script. With the Sweep parameters option in dymola, i need to do manually every single time

Comment: Not really, the UI for Sweep Parameters create a command that is executed. You can execute the same kind of commands from your scripts. If you want a more low-level command, simulateModelMulti also runs on multiple cores.